# Have two div elements with no space between them

Tags: html, css, space

I'm working on a website where I need to change the content of 2 div elements (add some text). Until now the 2 divs where glued together but when I did change their content an unexpected space appeared.
Does someone know how do I prevent this space from appearing (using Css I suppose) ?

Comment: Do the div's have a set pixel width? I think you are going to have to give us a little more info.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or demonstration on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Post a code sample (preferably on http://jsfiddle.net/). And who votes up on questions like this? You can't even see the code and you favorite the question...whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of the html some guesswork is required here, but the likeliest answer is that one of the elements inside the div has a margin that extends beyond the div's boundary.